# Producing a simple line graph

Tags: sql, ms-access, graph, ms-access-2007

I am using MS Access 2007. This is a really simple problem, but I cannot work out how to do it.

I have the following table produced from a query:

```
 1     2     3     4
1000  5500  9500  3000
```

I want to produce a line chart of the data.

The columns headings are respectively:

```
SumOfA1    SumOfA2    SumOfA3    SumOfA4
```

How do I do this?

Comment: If those values are the y-axis, what is the x-axis value?  1, 2, 3, 4?

Comment: What software do you want to render the graph?  Excel for desktop, d3 for web....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what Excel can do with it:

[image]